# How to create a table with numbered equations?

Tags: tables, equations, align

I am trying to recreate a table with equations (numbered) in them but for some reason I cannot get it to work. I tried to used custom equation numbers where I added equation numbers manually, I tried with align (which seems to be the most promising) and some other methods that didn't work. I've made an example in Word how I want it to look like:

[image: Table example]

And this is currently how I recreated it in LateX

[image: Latex table]

However, the problem is that the equations are not aligned and that the whole table is wider than the textwidth even though I set the columns that together they are equal to the textwidth `p{0.15\textwidth}|p{0.85\textwidth}`. The reason I use a parbox is that it allows me to use numbered equations in a table which is a solution I also found on this forum.

This is the code I used for the table.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\lipsum[5]

\begin{table}[htb]
    \caption{Test table}
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.15\textwidth}|p{0.85\textwidth}}
        \toprule
        Molar gas flow & \parbox{0.85\textwidth}{\begin{align}
        \frac{\mathrm{d} \mathrm{F}_{\mathrm{k}}}{\mathrm{d} \mathrm{V}_{\mathrm{R}}} &=\mathrm{S}_{\mathrm{k}, \mathrm{r}} \pm \mathrm{S}_{\mathrm{k}, \mathrm{be}} \end{align}} \\
        Molar solid flow & \parbox{0.85\textwidth}{\begin{align}
        \frac{\mathrm{d} \mathrm{F}_{\mathrm{m}}}{\mathrm{d} \mathrm{V}_{\mathrm{R}}} &=\mathrm{S}_{\mathrm{m}, \mathrm{r}} \pm \mathrm{S}_{\mathrm{m}, \mathrm{we}} \end{align}} \\
        Energy balance & \parbox{0.85\textwidth}{\begin{align}
        \frac{\mathrm{d} \mathrm{U}_{\mathrm{R}}}{\mathrm{d} \mathrm{V}_{\mathrm{R}}} &=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} \mathrm{V}_{\mathrm{R}}}\left[\mathrm{T}_{\mathrm{R}} \sum \mathrm{C}_{\mathrm{p}, \mathrm{k}} \mathrm{F}_{\mathrm{k}}+\sum \mathrm{C}_{\mathrm{p}, \mathrm{m}} \mathrm{F}_{\mathrm{m}}\right]=\mathrm{S}_{\mathrm{h}, \mathrm{R}}+\mathrm{S}_{\mathrm{h}, \mathrm{ext}} \end{align}} \\
        Pressure balance & \parbox{0.85\textwidth}{\begin{align}
        \frac{\mathrm{d} \mathrm{p}_{\mathrm{R}}}{\mathrm{d} \mathrm{V}_{\mathrm{R}}} &=\frac{\nabla \mathrm{p}_{\mathrm{R}}}{\mathrm{A}_{\mathrm{R}}} \end{align}} \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I don't mind too much that the unit column is missing as long as my equation are numbered as I want to refer to them in my text.

Basically my questions comes down to: **How can I recreate the first table in LaTeX with equation numbers?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tabular*`, with a small trick to get the equation number.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{a4wide} % deprecated because /very/ buggy
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\lipsum[5]

The reference~\eqref{test}.

\begin{table}[htb]
\newcommand{\stepequation}{\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)} % local command
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % local setting

\caption{Test table}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l % parameter name
  >{$\displaystyle}r<{$} % left-hand side
  @{\extracolsep{0pt}}
  >{$\displaystyle{}}l<{$} % right-hand side
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  >{\stepequation}r
}

\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Parameter} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Balances} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
\\
\midrule
Molar gas flow & 
\frac{\mathrm{d} \mathrm{F}_{\mathrm{k}}}{\mathrm{d} \mathrm{V}_{\mathrm{R}}}
  &=\mathrm{S}_{\mathrm{k}, \mathrm{r}} \pm \mathrm{S}_{\mathrm{k}, \mathrm{be}}
& \label{test}
\\
\addlinespace
Molar solid flow &
\frac{\mathrm{d} \mathrm{F}_{\mathrm{m}}}{\mathrm{d} \mathrm{V}_{\mathrm{R}}} 
  &=\mathrm{S}_{\mathrm{m}, \mathrm{r}} \pm \mathrm{S}_{\mathrm{m}, \mathrm{we}}
&
\\
\addlinespace
Energy balance &
\frac{\mathrm{d} \mathrm{U}_{\mathrm{R}}}{\mathrm{d} \mathrm{V}_{\mathrm{R}}}
  &=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} \mathrm{V}_{\mathrm{R}}}
    \left[\mathrm{T}_{\mathrm{R}}
      \sum \mathrm{C}_{\mathrm{p}, \mathrm{k}} \mathrm{F}_{\mathrm{k}}+
      \sum \mathrm{C}_{\mathrm{p}, \mathrm{m}} \mathrm{F}_{\mathrm{m}}
    \right]
    =\mathrm{S}_{\mathrm{h}, \mathrm{R}}+\mathrm{S}_{\mathrm{h}, \mathrm{ext}}
&
\\
\addlinespace
Pressure balance &
\frac{\mathrm{d} \mathrm{p}_{\mathrm{R}}}{\mathrm{d} \mathrm{V}_{\mathrm{R}}}
  &=\frac{\nabla \mathrm{p}_{\mathrm{R}}}{\mathrm{A}_{\mathrm{R}}}
&
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Beware that `a4wide` has been deprecated for a long time because it is buggy and doesn't behave with other software such as `hyperref`.

Answer (score 0):

Do not load `a4wide`, which shouldn't be used any more (cf. `l2tabu`, p.1).

You don't need a `tabular` environment inside `table`, so I propose to simply use a `flalign` environment. I simplified your code, in particular with the `\diff` command from `esdiff`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools,esdiff}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\lipsum[5]

\begin{table}[htb]
 \caption{Test table}\vspace*{-1.5ex}
 \begin{spreadlines}{12pt}
 \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{-8pt}
\begin{flalign}
\notag\\[-2\jot]
\toprule\addlinespace
\enspace & \textsf{Molar gas flow} & \mathrm{\diff{F_{k}}{V_{R}}} &=\mathrm{S_{k, r} \pm S_{k, be}} & & \\
& \textsf{Molar solid flow }& \mathrm{\diff{F_{m}}{V_{R}}} &= \mathrm{S_{m, r} \pm S_{m, we}} \\
& \textsf{Energy balance} & \mathrm{\diff{U_{R}}{V_{R}}} &=\mathrm{\diff{}{V_{R}}\left[T_{R} \sum C_{p, k} F_{k}+\sum C_{p, m} F_{m}\right]=S_{h, R}+S_{h, ext}} \\
& \textsf{Pressure balance} & \mathrm{\diff{p_R}{V_{R}}}&=\mathrm{\frac{\nabla p_{R}}{A_{R}}}\\
\addlinespace\bottomrule
\notag
\end{flalign}
\end{spreadlines}
\end{table}
\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

[image]